# Как сделать, чтобы функция ВСЕГДА выполнялась в отдельном потоке

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть функция таймера, которая используется в tkinter программе. Если запускать её в том же потоке, что и поток окна приложения, всё зависает. Поэтому функция таймера должна вызываться в отдельном потоке.

```
def timer(timing = 1, target = do_nothing, args2 = []):
    if target == False:
        time.sleep(timing)
    else:
        time.sleep(timing)
        target(*args2)
```

Но проблема в том, что timer может вызываться еще много откуда, и вызывается он всегда в потоке окна. Мне нужно, чтобы эта функция вызывалась ТОЛЬКО в своём потоке независимо от того, откуда она была вызвана.

Comment: В tkinter лучше не использовать os.sleep() для задержки, есть более удобные методы
https://www.delftstack.com/ru/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-use-a-timer-in-tkinter/

Comment: Вызов `root.after(timing*1000, target, *args2)` не подходит?